# In-App:My iOS app is rejected due to auto-renewable In- App Purchase subscription so how to create auto-renewable In- App Purchase subscription ?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Currently my iphone app is rejected by Apple and the reason they gave is

---

We found that your Newsstand app does not offer at least one Auto-Renewable Subscription In App Purchase product, as required by the iTunes Connect Developer Guide:

"To submit a Newsstand app, your app must be enabled for Newsstand, offer at least one auto-renewable In- App Purchase subscription, and the Info.plist of the associated binary must include UINewsstandApp=true. In addition, UINewsstandIcon must be included in the CFBundleIcons key."

Complying with the requirements of the iTunes Connect Developer Guide is specified in Schedule 2 of the iOS Developer Program License Agreement, and is therefore a requirement of the App Store Review Guidelines.

It would be appropriate to revise your app to offer at least one Auto-Renewable Subscription In App Purchase and resubmit a new binary, and its In App Purchase(s), for review."

---

So my questions are

```
    1.How to create one auto-renewable In- App Purchase subscription ? 
    2.Why i should include in  Info.plist UINewsstandApp=true.
    3.What is UINewsstandIcon ? How i include it in the CFBundleIcons key.?
```

Thanks

Comment: It's stated in their response what you should do. Clarify and be specific in what you're trying to ask.

Comment: hey vpdn, if you don't get any clue from question then comment it you should not down the vott..... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to look into how create in app purchases. To make an in app purchase `auto renew` its a case of simply marking the checkbox for that option during the IAP process
2. This is simply telling to you mark your app as a newstand app, again simply selecting that option in your info plist will do, this is telling your app to appear on Newstand.
3. A  Newstand icon is like a normal icon but with a different ratio thats all.

Apples way of telling you something can seem complicated but in reality you are just being asked to make sure app is for newstand,  create an appropriatley sized icon, and to add an auto renew subscription

Ive included some links for you

https://developer.apple.com/newsstand/

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html